# Gridview implementation for widget in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to implement the app widget which uses a 3x3 grid view I.e matrix.  I want to resize the app widget in such a way that when the grid is resized, the grid changes (row / columns) itself according to the size that I've selected. But when I try to change the size. instead of changing the matrix, it is reducing or increasing the size of the elements in the grid. I don't want the elements to get resized but I want the matrix to change according to the size of the widget icon. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks in advance.

//Widget Provider class

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
   {
        public static String EXTRA_WORD= "com.manthanstudio.listwidget.WORD";

```
      @SuppressLint("NewApi")
      public void onUpdate(Context ctxt, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int[] appWidgetIds) 
      {
        for (int i=0; i<appWidgetIds.length; i++) 
        {
          Intent svcIntent=new Intent(ctxt, WidgetService.class);

          svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
          svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

          RemoteViews widget=new RemoteViews(ctxt.getPackageName(),
                                              R.layout.widget);

          widget.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.words,
                                  svcIntent);

          Intent clickIntent=new Intent(ctxt, MainActivity.class);
          PendingIntent clickPI=PendingIntent.getActivity(ctxt,      0,clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

          widget.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.words, clickPI);

          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], widget);
        }

        super.onUpdate(ctxt, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
      }
```